# possible placement of rooks on chessboard with restrictions

Tags: probability, combinatorics

> Given 8 rooks:
>
> 1) what is the probability that 3 rooks are placed on black squares and 5 on white squares?
>
> 2) what is the probability that there's only one rook on a each row and column?

I think that in total there can be $\binom{64}{8}$ possible positions for the rooks because there're 64 squares in a chessboard. Then:

1) there're $\binom{32}{3}$ way to place 3 rooks on black square and there're $\binom{32}{5}$ ways to place 5 rooks on white squares. Thus in total there're $\frac{\binom{32}{3}\binom{32}{5}}{\binom{64}{8}}$ ways.

2) this is an equivalent of permutation of 8 objects in a row. Once we place a rook on row $x$ and column $y$, there remain $x-1$ and $y-1$ possibilities for future placements. Thus the answer is $\frac{8!}{\binom{64}{8}}$.

Please let me know if my logic is correct.

Comment: I think it's good! I can't find any gap.

Comment: You are getting correct answers or not?

Comment: For the sake of computing probability, you need to take identical arrangements into account.

What do I mean?

Well, you are correct in the assumption that there are $\binom{64}{8}$ **different** ways to arrange $8$ identical rooks on a chessboard with $64$ different squares.

However, in order to compute the probability of some specific type of arrangements, you need to account for **all** arrangements, and consider any pair of identical arrangements as distinguishable.

In this case, think of the rooks as **different**.

Comment: So the answer to the first question, for example, is $\dfrac{\frac{32!}{3!}\cdot\frac{32!}{5!}}{\frac{64!}{8!}}$.